# CosmosDB Geospatial query returns nothing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am exploring Azure's CosmosDB using the MongoDB interface. I wrote the following test (using Jest). Most of my other tests I can swap the MongoDB url for a CosmosDB url and they will run and pass. This test passes when pointed at MongoDB and fails with a CosmosDB url:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

let client, db, collection
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
const dbName = 'test'
describe('talking to mongodb', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(url)
    db = client.db(dbName)
    collection = db.collection('cities')
    await collection.createIndex({ location: '2dsphere' })
  })

  afterEach(async () => {
    await collection.drop()
    client.close()
  })

  it('it can find geocoded things', async () => {
    await collection.insertMany([
      {
        city: 'Ottawa, Canada',
        location: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [-75.69719309999999, 45.4215296],
        },
        bbox: [-76.35391589999999, 44.962733, -75.2465979, 45.5375801],
      },
      {
        city: 'Moscow, Russia',
        location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [37.6172999, 55.755826] },
        bbox: [37.3193289, 55.48992699999999, 37.9456611, 56.009657],
      },
    ])

    let cursor = await collection.find({
      location: {
        $near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-79.3831843, 43.653226] },
        $maxDistance: 500000,
      },
    })
    let [doc] = await cursor.toArray()

    expect(doc.city).toEqual('Ottawa, Canada')
  })
})
```

This test fails with the following error:

```
  ● talking to mongodb › it can find geocoded things

    MongoError: Request is malformed

      at node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:769:34
      at handleCallback (node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:178:5)
      at setCursorDeadAndNotified (node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:545:3)
      at nextFunction (node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:768:14)
      at node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:665:7
      at queryCallback (node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:263:5)
      at node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:542:18
```

Keep in mind, that query works in MongoDB. With a little tinkering I can get a query that works in MongoDB, and does not generate an Error in CosmosDB:

```
db.cities.find({"location": { $near:{ $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-79.3831843, 43.653226] }, $maxDistance: 500000 }}})
```

However that query returns nothing on CosmosDB.

What do I need to do to get that query to return results and get that test passing on CosmosDB?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737508/why-azure-documentdb-creates-index-on-each-path-by-default), Azure Cosmos DB creates indexes on every field automatically. So you no longer need to create an index on location in your Node.js code.

This would work if you recreate the collection without creating any indexes:

[image]

**See also:**

[Geospatial index querying doesn't work on Azure CosmosDB (DocumentDB) using the Mongo API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937937/geospatial-index-querying-doesnt-work-on-azure-cosmosdb-documentdb-using-the)